# Media querie está ignorando atributos

Tags: css3, layout-responsivo, media-queries

Estou tentando que uma `DIV` apenas seja mostrada em telas pequenas, então defini o seguinte:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 460px) {
    #bloco{
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: rgb(150,125,24);
    }
```

fora do mediaquerie está

```
#bloco{
    display:none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgb(230,25,24);
}
```

porém não funciona. Testei o contrario:

```
display:none;
```

no css padrão e

```
display: block;
```

no breakpoint e funcionou,
porque isso tá acontecendo?

Comment: Harry, como está o conteúdo exatamente? se o código que vale para as demais resoluções estiver depois da midiaquerie, ela vai sobrescrever o que você definiu na mesma...

Comment: No primeiro código tá faltando fechar as chaves.

Comment: o codigo das demais resoluções está depois. Todas as midiasqueies tem que ficar no final, após o código "principal"? por isso que alguns atributos não funcionam?

Comment: @Taisbevalle eu esqueci de cola o fechamento da chave aqui, mas no meu codigo ta fechada.

Comment: !important e seja feliz.

Comment: O que exatamente não está funcionando ? Qual atributo está sendo ignorado ? É o `display` ? Está tudo na mesma folha de estilo ? Como está o html do elemento `bloco`, possui algum `style`direto no html ?

Comment: A princípio, coloque todas as suas midiaqueries no final...

Comment: @MagicHat o atributo `display:none` não funciona. a div aparece em tela maior, mas não aparece em largura menor que 460px: quero exatamente o contrario, só aparecer em tela pequena. Parece que a mediaquerie está sendo sobreposta.

Comment: Só com esse fragmento de código que colocou, não creio ser possível afirmar de modo preciso a causa. Coloque o `html` e `css` da página respectiva, e certamente você terá a solução.

Comment: @MagicHat segui a dica do kennyRafael e funcionou. Pus as midiaqueries no fim do CSS. Obrigado a tds.

Comment: obrigado @KennyRafael

Comment: Disponha.... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O CSS possui o comportamento de leitura de cima para baixo, aplicando a regra que encontra por último.

Geralmente quando usamos media queries, elas acabam utilizando os mesmo seletores que já utilizamos anteriormente para definir algum padrão "genérico", portanto você precisa colocar a sua definição de media query ao final do arquivo para que ela sobrescreva as definições feitas anteriormente.

Vale lembrar que é uma boa prática realizar esse procedimento, pois facilita a busca por media queries, já que elas sempre estarão ao final do arquivo.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Muito obrigado. Esse macete ajudou muito.